# understanding matplotlib set_bad colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, missing-data, colormap

I am running the following code snip:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cm = ListedColormap(['green','red'])
cm.set_bad(color="black")
cm(np.nan)
```

I would expect cm(np.nan) to be return black, but it does return green.
How to determine the color corresponding to bad/masked/nan/missing values?

Comment: Nope, `cm(np.nan)` returns `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` for me, which last I checked was black [RGBA = (0,0,0,1) = #000000]. I'm using version 3.3.3

Comment: What is your version? Looks like `cm(np.nan)` returned green for versions < 3.2 and was fixed for v.3.2, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14257)

Comment: I am using 2.2.2. Well explained. could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cm(np.nan)` for earlier versions of matplotlib would return the color for `set_under` (which seems to default to green for you) instead of `set_bad`. This was fixed for version 3.2, see [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14257).

On version >= 3.2, this works as expected:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

matplotlib.__version__
# '3.3.3' 

cm = ListedColormap(['green','red'])
cm.set_bad(color="black")

cm(np.nan)
# (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

IOW, just `pip install --update matplotlib` to get the latest version with the expected behavior.